# Pandas DateTime index resampling not working

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe as shown in the code below. I am trying to "resample"
the data to get daily count of the ticket column. It does not give any error but the
resampling it not wokring. This is a sample of a much larger dataset. I want to be
able to get counts by day, week, month quarter etc. But the .resample option is
not giving me a solution. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-07-30T00:00:00','22:15:00','car'],
                    ['2013-10-12T00:00:00','0:10:00','bus'],
                    ['2014-03-31T00:00:00','9:06:00','ship'],
                    ['2014-03-31T00:00:00','8:15:00','ship'],
                    ['2014-03-31T00:00:00','12:06:00','ship'],
                    ['2014-03-31T00:00:00','9:24:00','ship'],
                    ['2013-10-12T00:00:00','9:06:00','ship'],
                    ['2018-03-31T00:00:00','9:06:00','ship']],
                    columns=['date_field','time_field','transportation'])
df['date_field2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_field'])
df['time_field2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_field'],unit = 'ns').dt.time
df['date_time_field'] = df.apply(lambda df : pd.datetime.combine(df['date_field2'],df['time_field2']),1)
df.set_index(['date_time_field'],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['date_field','time_field','date_field2','time_field2'],inplace=True)
df['tickets']=1
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['transportation'],inplace=True)
df.resample('D').sum()
print('\ndaily resampling:')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget assign output to variable like:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').sum()
print (df1)
```

Also your code should be simplify:

```
#join columns together with space and pop for extract column
df['date_field'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_field']+ ' ' + df.pop('time_field'))
#create and sorting DatetimeIndex, remove column
df = df.set_index(['date_field']).sort_index().drop(columns=['transportation'])
#resample counts
df1 = df.resample('D').size()
print (df1)
date_field
2013-10-12    2
2013-10-13    0
2013-10-14    0
2013-10-15    0
2013-10-16    0
             ..
2019-07-26    0
2019-07-27    0
2019-07-28    0
2019-07-29    0
2019-07-30    1
Freq: D, Length: 2118, dtype: int64
```

---

Also I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely great explanation, especially since I was going down the inplace route a lot unnecessarily it seems.